# Facebook API: Determine how many recipients of FB.ui send method

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

My WP site allows users to send messages to other FB users with the `FB.ui()` send method:

```
          FB.ui(
              method: 'send',
              name: 'Bla Bla Bla',
              link: 'http://www.example.com',
              show_error: true,
              display: 'popup'
              },

              function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if ( data.success=true ) {
                    console.log('SUCCESS');                 
                    jQuery.post('http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',               {
                            action : 'my_ajax_function',
                            user_id: '###',
                            postID : MyAjax.postID
                        }, function(returned) { console.log(returned);  }
                    );                  

                } else {
                    console.log('Failed to send FB invite');
                };
             }   
              );
```

As you can see, I'm making an AJAX call in the callback function. I'd really like that AJAX call to have **access to the number of recipients who just received the message.** When I log the data passed into the callback function, I don't see any useful info besides `success : true`.

Anyone know of a way to retrieve the number of recipients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I log the data passed into the callback function, I don't see any useful info besides success : true

And that’s only because you are *setting* the value of data.success yourself – `data.success=true` is **not** a comparison, it’s an assignment.

> Anyone know of a way to retrieve the number of recipients?

There is no direct way of doing that, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/:

> “If sending the message is successful, the user will be redirected to the redirect_uri. Otherwise, an error will be shown. *Unlike the Like Button, there is no return value per se.*”

You *could* try to find the message that the user just send via the `user/outbox` connection after asking for `read_mailbox` permission – but you’d still have to figure out which message in there is the right one by looking at the `created_time` and/or `message` content.

Comment: Woops about the `data.success=true`. That's a typo. It should be `data.success==true`, which does work at least because despite what the documentation says, this gets returned: `({success:true})` when I log the returned data.